# BasicArrowButton Height

Tags: java, size, height, overriding

I am trying to change my BasicArrowButtons to be taller or to change it's minimum sizes for when I put it in the south of the panel. So far I try to override paint(Graphics g) to use my fontSize rather than its defaultSize, but that doesn't change how it is fit in the panel.

```
        rightUsers=new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.LEFT){

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g)
          {
            super.paint(g);
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            int x = insets.left
                    + (bounds.width - insets.left - insets.right - fontSize) / 2;
            int y = insets.top
                    + (bounds.height - insets.left - insets.right - fontSize) / 2;
            paintTriangle(g, x, y, fontSize, direction, isEnabled());
          }
  };
```

If there is a way to change defaultSize, to my size that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

The source of BasicArrowButton can be found here:

http://www.jdocs.com/javase/7.b12/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicArrowButton.html

The `paint()` function uses `getSize()` to determine the size of the button. You could try using `setSize`, or alternatively you could try copy/pasting that code and making the changes you want.

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried to do that and those methods don't appear to affect it at all.

Comment: I changed the answer. Take a look at the new one.